# Vue Router Meta object is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using a Meta object in my Vue Router to dynamically set layouts in my views/pages, but I can't see the Meta values when I console.log the Vue Route. I can see the Meta object, but my 'layout' value is not there at all.

I'm not sure if I'm setting this value wrong or why it's not showing.

```
{
path: "/",
name: "Home",
meta: { layout: "predashboard" },
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "../views/Home.vue"),
}
```

[image]

Comment: "_when I console.log the Vue Route_" Can you please show the code that you tried. Also, please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: Are you sure you are on route `Home` when checking the `meta` Object?

Comment: @palash I added a screen shot of what I see using the Vue Chrome tool.

Comment: @adamorlov Yes, check out the image I just added.

Comment: @LuisRodriguez it is strage that there is no `name` parametr in your `route` Object you have posted. I think that's the case.